# Storing short audio file / Streaming in app

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I plan on making an app that utilizes the Parse.com  backend for User authentication / Posts / Followers / etc. I want for users to be able to upload a sample music file to Parse (or an alternate solution) then be able to stream or have others be able to stream it. I was told it's possible to store the file using PFFile, but how about as far as streaming it?

Also would this be against Apple rules since ultimately it will allow users to buy these music files through the app, or would I have to use iTunes accounts/files of some sort?

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: i dont think server's at parse do the 'chunked-encoding' required for streaming to other user's of the app. They are optimize for thruput. You can upload audio and have users download the entire audio prior to opening a player on it.

Comment: Hrm not sure how exactly how I would go about doing that...

Comment: well u could start reading docs on file upload   https://parse.com/docs/rest#files-uploading  you just put your binary audio file in the body of a POST and use the api as in the example.

Answer (score 7):

In terms of uploading it to parse:

```
PFObject *testObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"TestObject"];

//get the audio in NSData format
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"02 Interstellar Overdrive" ofType:@"m4a"];
NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

//create PFFile to store audio data
PFFile *audioFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"02 Interstellar Overdrive.m4a" data:audioData];
testObject[@"audioFile"] = audioFile;

//save
[testObject saveInBackground];
```

In terms of streaming it from the Parse servers use AVPlayer which allows streaming. You can use AVAudioPlayer if you want to download the whole song first before playing:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"TestObject"];
[query whereKeyExists:@"audioFile"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error)
    {
        PFObject *testObject = [objects lastObject];
        PFFile *audioFile = testObject[@"audioFile"];
        NSString *filePath = [audioFile url];

        //play audiofile streaming
        self.avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]];
        self.avPlayer.volume = 1.0f;
        [self.avPlayer play];

    } else {

        NSLog(@"error = %@", [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

Can't speak to whether Apple will let you sell music in your app or not.