# Trouble storing Audio on Parse in an m4a format

Tags: ios, audio, parse-platform, m4a, aiff

I am trying to record audio using [the amazing audio engine](http://theamazingaudioengine.com/) and then upload it to Parse.

There is a great question on stackoverflow which seems to deal with this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781604/storing-short-audio-file-streaming-in-app/19994147#19994147) but I am having problems with the m4a formatting side of things meaning this answer doesn't help me.

This is how I record audio:

```
self.recorder = [[AERecorder alloc] initWithAudioController:_audioController];

NSArray * documentsFolders = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * path = [documentsFolders[0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Recording.aiff"];
```

And then how I save it to Parse:

```
NSArray * documentsFolders = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * path = [documentsFolders[0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Recording.aiff"];

NSData * audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];

PFObject * testObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"TestObject"];

PFFile * audioFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"audio.aiff" data:audioData];

testObject[@"audioFile"] = audioFile;
[testObject saveInBackground];
```

This all works fine and the audio is uploaded and saved correctly.

The problem is that I am saving the audio in an **aiff** format, this means it takes longer to stream and upload as it is a larger file. I really want to save the audio in an m4a format as speed is more of an issue than quality.

I find though when I change .aiff to .m4a suddenly it doesn't work.

- When I click on the data in Parse, whereas before I could hear the audio, now the url doesn't play
- Loading it back and playing it on the app doesn't play it when it did before.

Is there something I am doing wrong or overlooking? I feel that this should be a quick an easy change so any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try telling the AERecorder to use M4A format and see if that helps (in addition to changing the filenames.)

```
[self.recorder prepareRecordingToFileAtPath:path fileType:kAudioFileM4AType error:nil];
```

Or setting that fileType in beginRecording.

http://theamazingaudioengine.com/doc/interface_a_e_recorder.html#pub-methods

Comment: As a note, the prepareRecording function takes a fraction of a second to run meaning any changes will also be delayed (button changing on press), having the recorder always running and preparing the file before in the background then calling AERecorderStartRecording(); can get round this by moving the stutter to a less obvious time.